# React-Native - Not Recognising Function In Native Module Wrapper

Tags: android, react-native

I need to interface with a printer through react-native. the printer has an android SDK, which consists of an .aar file. I have followed the steps outlined in the following article, to create a wrapper for accessing the SDK:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

However, when I try to call my custom loadPrinters function, I get an error. My code is as follows:

PrinterModule.java

```
package com.printertest;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;

public class PrinterModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
   PrinterModule(ReactApplicationContext context){
    super(context);
}

@Override
public String getName(){
    return "PrinterModule";
}

@ReactMethod
public void ListPrinters(){
    //return "Checking for printers";
}
}
```

MyAppPackage.java

```
package com.printertest;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class MyAppPackage implements ReactPackage{

@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext){
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
            ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

    modules.add(new PrinterModule(reactContext));

    return modules;
}


}
```

In MainApplication.java i've then added the custom wrapper to getPackages..

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      packages.add(new MyAppPackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

My app.js react code is then as follows:

```
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  NativeModules,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

...

const { printerModule } = NativeModules;
const onPress = () => { 
setText(printerModule.ListPrinters());
```

}

As far as I can tell, ive followed the above example exactly. Yet every time I get the following error:

Cannot read property "ListPrinters" of null

There are no errors in the console (one warning about flatDir not being recomemnded). I can see the 3rd party SDK has been imported correctly, although Im not actually calling it yet (removed for simplicity).

ALso, I know i'm setting the text to nothing, Listprinters() is currently returning nothing - but i'd like the function to stop crashing first before I implement anything here.

I've seen some other examples saying I cant return values from Listprinters - ive tried using callbacks, but the problem seems to be calling the function in the first place, not with the response.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to console log the printerModule.ListPrinters, what the output you are getting?

Comment: @VickyAhuja this function doesnt execute. it crashes the app when its called with the error listed above.

Comment: No, we don't have to call as of now, just check whether you are able to see the function in the  console or not

Answer (score 0):

I think I found error in your `app.js`, here: `const { printerModule } = NativeModules;`

The module name you define in `app.js`(printerModule) is different from the one you declared in `PrinterModule.java`(PrinterModule).

Remember add a log in `ListPrinters` function to check.

Please change `printerModule` to `PrinterModule` and try again.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but isn't this just a variable decleration? Therefore case doesnt matter here, it's defining a variable to refer to it locally.

Comment: @GavinCoates It is not a variable. `getName()` method in your module.java file will return a string, which represents the name of the native module. You need you that name be like a variable when you call that module in React Native.

More information here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#module-name